Issue with screen flickering on Ubuntu with a gaming monitor
I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 on my custom-built PC, and I'm experiencing an issue with my gaming monitor. The screen occasionally flickers, especially when browsing or watching videos. I'm using a gaming monitor connected via HDMI to an NVIDIA GTX 1650 graphics card.
Here are the steps I've tried so far:

Checked refresh rate: Ensured it’s set to 144Hz in the Display settings.
Installed NVIDIA drivers: Using proprietary drivers (version 525) from the "Additional Drivers" tool.
Tried different cables: Swapped the HDMI cable to rule out hardware issues.

Despite these efforts, the flickering persists. I suspect it might be related to:
Kernel Version: Currently on 5.15. Could a newer kernel help?
Display Manager: Using GNOME with X11. Would Wayland be better?
Monitor-Specific Configuration: Are there any tweaks specific to gaming monitors in Ubuntu?
Has anyone faced similar issues with gaming monitors on Ubuntu? Any advice or configurations that worked for you would be greatly appreciated!
Here is some additional system information:
   CPU: Ryzen 5 3600
   RAM: 16GB
   Monitor Resolution: 1920x1080

Check to see if G-sync or free-sync is enabled in the Nvidia (on windows Nvidia control panel) make sure your monitor supports one of the two. This was turned on by default when i installed but it wouldn't hurt to check.
